# Default Domain Name in kinit command

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, sh

I am running '**kinit**' command from **NSTask**. Once Task Launch it ask me for password as below

```
GaganTech@dce.psu.edu's password:
```

So my question: what is '`dce.psu.edu`' and is there any way to fetch this value via Objective-C?

I am working on a Mac app.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below links for detail

[Link1](https://wikispaces.psu.edu/display/clcmaclinuxwikipublic/macOS+Authentication+Configuration)  [Link2](http://kb.its.psu.edu/article/753)

Here is the file location *`/etc/krb5.conf`* in Mac system (PENN)

Below is the code to read the file

```
NSString* filePath = @"/etc/krb5.conf";
NSError *error = nil;
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedAlways error:&error];
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"response is: %@",response);
```

I got below response

```
response is: [domain_realm]
    .psu.edu = dce.psu.edu
    psu.edu = dce.psu.edu

[libdefaults]
    default_realm = dce.psu.edu
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
    forwardable = true
    noaddresses = true
```